# How to use image in my computer as a background image in xaringan

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I know the following code will make a background image of xaringan slide.

```
---
class: inverse, left, top
background-image: 
url("")
background-size: contain
```

But what if the image is not from web but from my computer. In that case, how should I put the link instead of `url()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply provide the file path of that image file inside the `url()`.

```
---
title: "Local Image file on Xaringan"
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---

## Adding local Image

The process of adding local image file (file from computer) is similar to that
of images from web. Simply provide the path to that image file in `url()`. For
example, suppose the jpg file `lights.jpg` is in the working directory. So we 
can simply reference to it as `url("lights.jpg")`.

---
class: title-slide, top, left, inverse
background-image: url("lights.jpg")
background-size: cover
```